# How to increase the font size of first two letters of any word/sentence?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make the font size bigger for first two letters of nav links. I know for first letter it can be achieved using `:first-letter`. However I have tried it using span like below and it's increasing the font size but not getting aligned horizontally. **About** and **Contact** links are moving to top, both should be aligned with rest of the links (from bottom). I don't want to set line-height to the main container because the sub links are supposed to display below the main links. Any idea about this?

```
<li><a href="#"><span>01</span> Architectural Design</a></li>
```

**CSS**

```
ul li a span {
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

```css
.nav {
  font-family: arial;
  background: #dddddd;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px;
}

a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  font-size: 12px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

ul li a span {
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>01</span> Architectural Design</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>02</span> Media</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>03</span> Developments</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: How do you want it to be aligned?

Comment: you can see about and contact links are moving to top. all should  be aligned with rest of the links(from bottom).

Comment: So does my answer work for you, or did you want the about and contact link to be aligned at the bottom?

Comment: Are you ever going to have more than 9 items?

Comment: No. these are the only links. @Cody I tried vertical-align top but it's showing in reverse manner, i wanted it from bottom.

Comment: What do you think of this solution? Then just edit the CSS for `ol li:before` to whatever you want to update the number styling: http://jsfiddle.net/ninty9notout/6ZZWB/

Comment: @ninty9notout let me try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may try this... old school but useful

```
<div class="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><span>&nbsp;</span>About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>01</span> Architectural Design</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>02</span> Media</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>03</span> Developments</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>&nbsp;</span>Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh, why did I not think in this way earlier. Anyway thanx dude. It works.

Answer (score 0):

If you add `vertical-align:top` to the `span`, it will align the words after the `span` to the top of the `span`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KhxnX/)

Other properties include

```
middle
bottom
baseline
```

Answer (score 0):

I would set the line-height of the li elements.

```
li{
    font-size:12px;
    float:left;
    margin-right:30px;
    line-height: 25px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KhxnX/1/)

I know you mentioned that you

> don't want to set line-height to the main container

but will this work for you?

Answer (score 0):

It can only be used with the pseudo elements `:before` that make your code much cleaner and easy to read.

```css
.empty:before {
  content: "";
  font-size: 25px;
}

.nav {
  font-family: arial;
  background: #dddddd;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px;
}

a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  font-size: 12px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

ul li a span {
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a class='empty' href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>01</span> Architectural Design</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>02</span> Media</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>03</span> Developments</a></li>
    <li><a class='empty' href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```